# Handle State change in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am still new to react, and I have to create this icon menu. My problem is that my handleChange right now is not working. I have the icon Menu, I can see the possibleValues menu, but I can't select any of them. Could someone explain the best way to make this code work? I am using Icon Menu component "https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/icon-menu". Thank you

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

class MatchPintOwnerFilter extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      values: [],
    };
  }

  handleChange(event, index, values) {
    this.setState({ values });
  }

  render() {
    const { possibleValues, title } = this.props;
    return (
      <SelectField
        autoWidth
        floatingLabelText={title}
        multiple={false}
        value={possibleValues}
        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
      >
        {Object.keys(possibleValues).map(possibleValue => (
          <MenuItem
            key={possibleValue}
            value={possibleValue}
            primaryText={possibleValues[possibleValue]}
          />
          ))}
      </SelectField>
    );
  }
}

MatchPintOwnerFilter.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  possibleValues: PropTypes.shape(),
  newValue: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]),
};

MatchPintOwnerFilter.defaultProps = {
  title: 'Frequency',
  possibleValues: {
    0: 'status 0',
    1: 'status 1',
    2: 'status 2',
    3: 'status 3',
    4: 'status 4',
    5: 'status 5',
  },
  newValue: '1',
};
export default MatchPintOwnerFilter;
```

Comment: In the snippet of code that you shared, you're using the SelectField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the SelectField **value** prop correctly:

```
const { possibleValues } = this.props;
< SelectField
autoWidth
floatingLabelText = {
  title
}
multiple = {
  false
}
value = {
  possibleValues
}
onChange = {
    this.handleChange.bind(this)
  } >
```

What you are trying to do is to control the SelectionField by passing a prop called possibleValues which never changes. If you want to create a controlled component you should lift the **State Up** and then pass it down to your component again as prop.

```
handleChange(event, index, value) {
   this.props.onSelectionFieldChange(value);
}
```

In your parent component you should have something like:

```
_onSelectionFieldChange(possibleValues) {
   this.setState({ possibleValues });
}

<MatchPintOwnerFilter onSelectionFieldChange={this._onSelectionFieldChange.bind(this)} possibleValues={this.state.possibleValues}>
```

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you need to pass value to value prop of SelectField but not possibleValues and never do binding directly in render instead do it in constructor
Keep your value state number but not an array

Check below corrected code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

class MatchPintOwnerFilter extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      value: 1,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event, index, value) {
    this.setState({ value });
  }

  render() {
    const { possibleValues, title, value } = this.props;
    return (
      <SelectField
        autoWidth
        floatingLabelText={title}
        multiple={false}
        value={value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      >
        {Object.keys(possibleValues).map(possibleValue => (
          <MenuItem
            key={possibleValue}
            value={possibleValue}
            primaryText={possibleValues[possibleValue]}
          />
          ))}
      </SelectField>
    );
  }
}

MatchPintOwnerFilter.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  possibleValues: PropTypes.shape(),
  newValue: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]),
};

MatchPintOwnerFilter.defaultProps = {
  title: 'Frequency',
  possibleValues: {
    0: 'status 0',
    1: 'status 1',
    2: 'status 2',
    3: 'status 3',
    4: 'status 4',
    5: 'status 5',
  },
  newValue: '1',
};
export default MatchPintOwnerFilter;
```